# Word VBA: Automating bookmark generation for individually numbered paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

## 1. Problem summary

This is my first time writing VBA for Word. I have multiple documents; each one is larger than 100 pp., with a plaintext index according to paragraph number. I am writing a script to find and bookmark paragraphs according to the numbering format used in my documents, in order to hyperlink index entries and/or cross-reference the documents.

## 2. Details

Numbering format is `{##-###.}` with chapter number before the hyphen and paragraph sequence number after. The original numbering does not contain leading zeroes.

I included a font color change in the script so that any paragraph numbers not captured as bookmarks will immediately stand out.

### Where I am stuck

- Current script matches the expression `{##-###.}` anywhere in the document; this is a problem because e.g. tables and figures are numbered using the same format as paragraphs. I need to somehow match this expression only with strings located at the start of a paragraph.
- Current script uses the `Bookmarks.Exists` method to check for a bookmark of the same *name* before creating one. I would like to check as well for a bookmark at the same *location* as `Selection.Start`, but have not yet learned how.

## 3. Script

```vb
' Variables:
'   pNum: verbatim result of the search expression
'   arrPNum: array containing padded two-digit chapter at (0) and padded three-digit paragraph at (1)
'   CleanPNum: chapter and paragraph reformatted into bookmark name

Sub makeBookmarks()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,3}."
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        Selection.Find.Execute
        pNum = Selection
        If pNum <> "" Then
            arrPNum = Split(Left(pNum, Len(pNum) - 1), "-")
            CleanPNum = "para_" & Format$(arrPNum(0), "00") & "_" & Format$(arrPNum(1), "000")
        End If
        If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(CStr(CleanPNum)) = True Then
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        Else
            Selection.Font.Color = 15132391
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
                .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=CStr(CleanPNum)
                .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
                .ShowHidden = False
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it would be easier if you used automatic numbering for your paragraph numbers and gave the paragraphs an outline level, perhaps level 9 using Heading 9 style. Word would automatically assign bookmarks for you to those numbers. Otherwise, you could use StyleRef for the chapter part of the number and a Seq field for the second part of the number. Do you want your numbering to have leading zeros?